# How to only return one particular column?

Tags: django, sqlite

I have model class `Bid` in my auction app that stores bids placed on items:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I want to query all bid prices placed on a particular item:

```
bids = Bid.objects.all().filter(title=title)
```

Returns all items with that title, but I just want the `price` column. I tried :

```
bids = bids.price
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only the prices based on the title of bid :

```
bids = Bid.objects.all().filter(title=title).values_list("price", flat = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop to get all prices:

```
bids = Bid.objects.filter(title=title)
for bid in bids:
    print(bid.price)
```

This is because [the query returns a list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).